# Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) not showing buttons (OSx App)?

Tags: macos, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to add push notification service (Remote) to my OSX app. I send the following payload and was able to get notification in my desktop. But the issue is with buttons.

```
{
"aps": {
"alert": {
    "title": "Game Request",
    "body": "Bob wants to play poker",
        "action-loc-key": "PLAY"
},
"badge": 5
},
"acme1": "bar",
"acme2": ["bang", "whiz"]
}
```

1. I am able to get the notification, but the button "Play" will show
   up only if I hover over the notification. Any thoughts on this behavior?
2. Also, Can I add multiple buttons as part of remote push notification
   ?
   I found some samples on iOS, but no concrete samples regarding OSx. Any help or guidance really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default "Notification style" is banner on OSx. Only for "Alert" style It will show buttons.  So changing to "Alert" it starts showing buttons.